# Using variables in PHP input radio name tag and get value on JQUERY or JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a PHP file that creates radio buttons based on pets ids.
The var $idperro is a number that changes dynamically to identify the set of radio buttons independently. I am trying to put the value inside the p tag.

Heres the PHP

```
<?php

echo '
    Jack Baño: <input type="radio" name="'.$idperro.'/servicio" value="'.$idperro.'/baño/'.$baño.'">
    Jack Corte: <input type="radio" name="'.$idperro.'/servicio" value="'.$idperro.'/corte/'.$corte.'">

    Pepe Baño: <input type="radio" name="'.$idperro.'/servicio" value="'.$idperro.'/baño/'.$baño.'">
    Pepe Corte: <input type="radio" name="'.$idperro.'/servicio" value="'.$idperro.'/corte/'.$corte.'">
    
    <p id="precio"></p>
';
?>
```

Heres the HTML output for that:

```
Jack baño: <input type="radio" name="8/servicio" value="8/baño/260.00">
Jack Corte: <input type="radio" name="8/servicio" value="8/corte/300.00">
Pepe baño: <input type="radio" name="17/servicio" value="17/baño/260.00">
Pepe Corte: <input type="radio" name="17/servicio" value="17/corte/300.00">
<p id="precio"></p>
```

I am trying to get the value of the selected radio button, but I cant set the name in Jquery in this fashion. (consider the var $idperro the dynamic var below. I know thats not the correct format for jquery and ive tried many things)

```
$("input[name=$idperro/servicio]").filter(":checked").val();
```

Is there any other way on which i can set a javascript function or jquery to get it.

Comment: Assuming `$idperro` is a php variable? If so, this won't exist when the JS runs.

Comment: Give the inputs a class, use that class as selector.

Comment: Using `input[name$="/servicio"]` should work too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this.

Add a class `yourClassName` for easy targeting with jQuery:

```html
Jack baño: <input class="yourClassName" type="radio" name="8/servicio" value="8/baño/260.00">
Jack Corte: <input class="yourClassName" type="radio" name="8/servicio" value="8/corte/300.00">
Pepe baño: <input class="yourClassName" type="radio" name="17/servicio" value="17/baño/260.00">
Pepe Corte: <input class="yourClassName" type="radio" name="17/servicio" value="17/corte/300.00">
<p id="precio"></p>
```

Then you could try:

```js
$("input.yourClassName:checked").val();
```